# How to change top and bottom page margins for odd and even pages?

Tags: latex, margin

I have a problem with my LaTeX code. I want to change page geometry for odd and even pages. However, i also have to change top margins differently for odd and even pages.

All answers for odd and even page margins include actually change in right margin.

I am runnnig TeXMaker in Ubuntu with a Texlive-full.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{25mm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{40mm} #These change only left margin
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more background? What is the purpose of the alternating margin size? For binding? For some headline or other page decoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332272/36296 maybe the following could help:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1cm,outer=2cm,landscape,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\headheight}{\ifodd\count\z@ 3cm\else 0.5cm\fi}{}{}
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\global\@colht\textheight}{\global\advance\textheight by\ifodd\count\z@ 2.5cm\else -2.5cm\fi\global\@colht\textheight}{}{}
\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, it solved my problem for my dissertation. I will cite your kind response in there.